Which functions/classes to export (and how to export them in a smart way) when google test is compiled in a visual studio DLL project
I succeeded in compiling a visual studio 2022 DLL project with google test sources. (See Building google test as a DLL in Visual Studio 2022 linking errors for more details.)
For now, no lib files is generated as I don't export any functions/classes, of course I need to export at least functions I need related to test case, fixtures and parametrised tests, but after a close look, doing it "linearly" (meaning, __declspec(dllexport)ing each needed class/function) seems a daunting task. Is there a smart way to do this ? (As it is after all not really proper to googletest.)

Your actual question is still "How to build GoogleTest DLL". What you have asked in the post is XY-problem - you did not build DLL properly but you think about modifying the GoogleTest sources instead of tuning proper build settings.
When you build a gtest.dll in VS and you don't use cmake, you should set the macro GTEST_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY=1 in the compiler settings.

Suggestion: use vcpkg install gtest or vcpkg add port gtest in the project manifest if you don't want to deal with cmake.

You're right ... I will try the preprocessor directive setting GTEST_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY to 1. I know about vcpkg but in my company we are only allowed to either fully integrate source or to use nuget packages ...
